# Can't access root-dir due to misconfiguration

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

that rewrites `example.com/index.php?page=something` to `example.com/something`.

This rewrite rule doesn't let me into `example.com/(some-file-here)`, for example:

```
example.com/favicon.ico
example.com/robots.txt
```

To show up the favicon, I simply put it into `/images/favicon.ico` and stuff like that, but I prefer a correct configured `.htaccess` and put `favicon.ico` and `robots.txt` into root dir.

What changes do I have to make in this rule so I can access `example.com/(some-file-here)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude your real files and folders from the rule, try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```